# Is it possible to pass sub-class of RowsSupportFragment to sub-class of BrowseSupportFragment?

Tags: kotlin, android-tv, leanback

I want to pass a sub-class of RowsSupportFragment of sub-class of BrowseSupportFragment, because I need to override some methods in RowsSupportFragment to change default behavior of RowsSupportFragment.

For example, to always show rows headers, by overriding setExpand() function to true.

The same question applies to sub-class of HeadersSupportFragment.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not much, because from what I see there is no way to override the RowsSupportFragment class and pass it to the sub-class of BrowseSupportFragment. The RowsSupportFragment instance is created in the BrowseSupportFragment by the factory, members are private and inner classes are final. The Leanback framework itself creates instances of RowsSupportFragment and HeadersSupportFragment and does not give you the option of overriding these classes and passing them to the sub-class BrowseSupportFragment.
You can only edit the presenters, but you can not change the default behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have not tested this, but I believe it should work.

In your `BrowseSupportFragment`, create a custom `FragmentFactory` for your sub-class and override the existing ListRow-pairing like this:

```java
getMainFragmentRegistry().registerFragment(ListRow.class, new FragmentFactory<CustomRowsSupportFragment>() {
            @Override
            public CustomRowsSupportFragment createFragment(Object row) {
                return new CustomRowsSupportFragment();
            }
       }
);
```

Comment: MainFragmentAdapterRegistry is a final class so it can't be extended

Comment: @kamilp Nowhere in my answer do I say anything about extending `MainFragmentAdapterRegistry`, I am simply registering a new fragment to it.

Comment: BrowseSupportFragment has private member where binds it 
private MainFragmentAdapterRegistry mMainFragmentAdapterRegistry =
            new MainFragmentAdapterRegistry();
There is no setter, so it can't be invoke in another way.

Comment: @kamilp You don't need to set it, you just need to access it. `getMainFragmentRegistry()` is public.

Comment: Works, thanks!
mainFragmentRegistry.registerFragment(ListRow::class.java, CustomListRowFragmentFactory()) solves this problem